# abs(int) function doesn't work as I'd expect

Tags: c++, avr, avr-gcc

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>

void Painter::draw_line(Point point_1, Point point_2, Color color)
{
    // Bresenham Algorithm
    if (point_1.x > point_2.x || (point_1.x == point_2.x && point_1.y > point_2.y))
    {
        swap(&point_1, &point_2);
    }

    int dx = abs((int)point_2.x - (int)point_1.x);
    int sx = point_1.x < point_2.x ? 1 : -1;
    int dy = abs((int)point_2.y - (int)point_1.y);
    int sy = point_1.y < point_2.y ? 1 : -1;
    int err = dx + dy;

    while ((point_1.x != point_2.x) && (point_1.y != point_2.y))
    {
        draw_pixel(point_1, color);
        if (2 * err >= dy)
        {
            err += dy;
            point_1.x += sx;
        }
        if (2 * err <= dx)
        {
            err += dx;
            point_1.y += sy;
        }
    }
}
```

It's supposed to calculate positions of pixels that will form a line.

The code above does not work properly - the lines are always horizontal. I found out that there is some issue with the `abs` function. When I replace the lines:

```cpp
int dx = abs((int)point_2.x - (int)point_1.x);
int sx = point_1.x < point_2.x ? 1 : -1;
int dy = abs((int)point_2.y - (int)point_1.y);
int sy = point_1.y < point_2.y ? 1 : -1;
int err = dx + dy;
```

with

```cpp
int dx = (int)point_2.x - (int)point_1.x >= 0 ? (int)point_2.x - (int)point_1.x : (int)point_1.x - (int)point_2.x;
int sx = point_1.x < point_2.x ? 1 : -1;
int dy = (int)point_2.y - (int)point_1.y <= 0 ? (int)point_2.y - (int)point_1.y : (int)point_1.y - (int)point_2.y;
int sy = point_1.y < point_2.y ? 1 : -1;
int err = dx + dy;
```

the program works properly!

Why is the version with `abs` not wroking properly?

For reference, here's my `Point` struct:

```cpp
struct Point {
    Point(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    uint16_t x;
    uint16_t y;
};
```

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to use a C-style cast (like for example `(int)point_2.x`) then it should almost always be taken as a sign that you're doing something wrong. If you need to convert a floating point value to an `int` then use e.g. `static_cast<int>(point_2.x)` instead.

Comment: Why are you using a "C" header? <stdlib.h>? In C++ use `cstdlib` or `cmath` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs. So you get those functions in the std namespace.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, @Pepijn, I'm using avr-gcc to compile the code. Neither `static_cast` or `cstdlib` seem to be available there. Although, I might be wrong, since I have no idea about C++

Comment: Don't pay attention to some programmer dude.  There is nothing wrong with C-style casts because there is nothing wrong with programming in C.  And anyway, we should try to keep the discussion focused on `abs`.

Answer (score 1):

Found the mistake!

```cpp
    int dx = abs((int)point_2.x - (int)point_1.x);
    int sx = point_1.x < point_2.x ? 1 : -1;
    int dy = -abs((int)point_2.y - (int)point_1.y);
    int sy = point_1.y < point_2.y ? 1 : -1;
    int err = dx + dy;
```

A minus was missing in front of the third expression.